# Unity3D Draggable GUI.Box with GUI controls

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I'm constructing a custom node editor window in Unity, and I've had a look at various resources such as [this one](http://gram.gs/gramlog/creating-node-based-editor-unity/), which uses `GUI.Box` to construct node windows.

This works great, and I'm able to drag these windows around the way I want, however once I add controls to the `GUI.Box`, I want them to override the `Drag()` function I've written.

Here's an example of the issue - When I move the vertical slider up, the entire box drags with it.

[image: Vertical Slider issues]

Is there a way to fix this behavior using `GUI.Box`, or should I go back to `GUI.Window` with its built-in `GUI.DragWindow()`?

Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using:

**EditorMouseInput.cs:**

```
private bool ActionLeftMouseDown()
{
    mouseDownNode = editor.GetSelectedNode(Input.current.mousePosition);

    if (mouseDownNode == null)
        editor.StartMovingEditorCanvas();
    else
        mouseDownNode.IsSelected = true;
}
```

**BaseNodeEditor.cs:**

```
public BaseNode GetSelectedNode(Vector2 mousePos)
{
    foreach (BaseNode node in Nodes)
    {
        if (node.WindowRect.Contains(mousePos))
            return node;
    }
    return null;
}

public void Drag(Vector2 delta)
{
    if (!MoveEditorMode && !ConnectionMode)
    {
        foreach (BaseNode node in Nodes)
        {
            node.Drag(delta);
        }
    }
```

**BaseNode.cs:**

```
public void Drag(Vector2 delta)
{
    if (IsSelected)
        draggedDistance += delta;
}
```

The vertical slider is added in the derived JumpNode class. Extract of the helper class that constructs the slider:

```
Vector2 pos = node.WindowRect.position + rect.position * GridSpacing;
value = GUI.VerticalSlider(new Rect(pos, rect.size * GridSpacing), value, maxValue, minValue);
```

I can see why this doesn't do what I want, but I don't know how to go about it given the GUI controls aren't part of the GUI.Box.

Any help or suggestions, even a nudge towards another source would be greatly appreciated - I feel I've used all the search terms that exist in my head!

**Edit - Solved:** Thanks to Kleber for solving this one for me. In case anyone else runs into this or a similar issue, the solution for me was in realising that GUI controls consume left mousedown events automatically, so clicking a slider means there's no propagation to the Box to check if it was clicked.

What I needed to do was separate the IsSelected and IsDragged flags in the Node class, and clear IsDragged on mouseUp. I originally used IsSelected to flag both drag enabled, and selected (multiple nodes could be selected and dragged at once).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite a complex tutorial so I didn't read it entirely, but the problem seems to be the `MouseDrag` detection. Well, basically you want to stop the event propagation when you click on a GUI element inside the Box, right? To do so, you call:

```
Event.current.Use()
```

every time the user drags the mouse on one of your components.

Using the resource you've mentioned, I altered the `Node` class and added a slider inside the `Draw()` method, ending like this:

```cs
public void Draw() {
    inPoint.Draw();
    outPoint.Draw();
    GUI.Box(rect, title, style);
    GUI.BeginGroup(rect);
    _value = GUI.HorizontalSlider(new Rect(20, 0, 50, 20), _value, 100, -100);
    GUI.EndGroup();
}
```

[image: First example]

Another thing you can do is change how you draw your window. Here it's a simple example that I've tested on the latest Unity version (5.6):

```cs
private void OnGUI() {
    GUI.Box(_rect, string.Empty);
    GUI.BeginGroup(_rect);

    _value = GUI.VerticalSlider(new Rect(145, 100, 20, 100), _value, 100, -100);
    GUI.EndGroup();

    var e = Event.current;
    if (e.type == EventType.MouseDrag && _rect.Contains(e.mousePosition)) {
        _rect.x += e.delta.x;
        _rect.y += e.delta.y;
        Repaint();
    }
}
```

As you can see, this example doesn't need an `Event.current.Use()` to work properly.

[image: Second example]

Comment: thanks for the response! Event.current.Use() would definitely work, although my problem lies in that the slider control (or any control) doesn't exist in the box, it's just drawn on top of it. I'm also using built in GUI controls, so I don't see the events when it's clicked, selected, dragged etc

Comment: `Event.current` is accessible only inside `OnGUI()`, so it's only for IMGUI system. The resource you sent has a use of `Event.current` sent as a parameter of `ProcessEvents()` method, for example. I edited my answer adding other solutions that could work.

Comment: First off I just want to give a huge thanks for taking your time on this one. i figured out the problem - it took a bit of a shift in thinking and you definitely helped me get there. I had a single MouseEventHandler script which didn't clear selections on mouseup (to enable selecting multiple boxes). I didn't realise the control consumes the event automatically, so I was looking in the wrong place. Dragging the Box meant it stayed selected when I dragged the slider.